# C: Update multiple records on file

Tags: c, file-io

This is a follow-up from this: [C: One pointer for reading and one pointer for updating the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615328/c-one-pointer-for-reading-and-one-pointer-for-updating-the-same-file).

The function `do_update()` seeks to update multiple records on a file depending on a condition. However, that function is not working:

```
void do_update(char name[]) {
    FILE *my_file;
    int records_read;
    int records_written;
    struct my_struct an_struct;
    struct my_struct empty_struct = {"", -1};

    my_file = fopen("consulta.dat", "rb+");

    records_read = fread(&an_struct, sizeof(struct my_struct), 1, my_file); 
    while (records_read == 1) {
        if(strcmp(name, an_struct.name) == 0){
            records_written = fwrite(&empty_struct, sizeof(struct my_struct),
                1, my_file);
            //At first match this returns one, other matches return 0.
            //It never updates the file
        }
        records_read = fread(&an_struct, sizeof(struct my_struct), 1, my_file); 
    }

    fclose(my_file);
}
```

The `fwrite` call is not changing the records on the file. I was checking the return value of this function and at first match it returns `1`, if there are another matches it returns `0`. However, when I open the file again no record was modified.

Anyone can give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. As this is a do-while loop you do not need the fread before the loop. do will always execute the block once. You will need to declare `long fileposition;`. In the first fseek, the -sizeof should move the file position back to the beginning of the structure just read and allow you to write. The second fseek should let you read again.

```
do {
    records_read = fread(&an_struct, sizeof(struct my_struct), 1, my_file); 
    if(strcmp(name, an_struct.name) == 0){
        fseek ( my_file, -sizeof(struct my_struct), SEEK_CUR);
        records_written = fwrite(&empty_struct, sizeof(struct my_struct),
            1, my_file);
        fileposition = ftell ( my_file);
        fseek ( my_file, fileposition, SEEK_SET);
    }
} while (records_read == 1);
```